# Different types of random effects in lme4

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am curious if there is a straightforward guide to the different types of random effects available for mixed-effects models.

I understand that `(1|var1)` is a random intercept, and adding `(var2|var1)` means that there is a random slope determined by `var2`. I have encountered examples of other options, which I do not totally under:

- `(1 + var2|var1)`
- `(0 + var2|var1)`
- `(var2||var1)`

What do these structures mean? Any similar structures, in addition, would be appreciated, too.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet  ; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90650/notation-for-multilevel-modeling maybe useful

Comment: Some useful info on the GLMM FAQ: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification

Comment: This book has some useful info: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387874579

Comment: if you can find the answers in one of these places, go ahead and answer your own question.  If not, wait a bit and someone (maybe me) will answer ...